# Deploying nodejs,mongodb,redis app with docker

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, docker-compose

I have an app that contains nodejs,mongodb and redis. I want to deploy this app to heroku. But I can't figure out how I can achieve this. I've read some articles. unfortunately, I'cant comprehend

docker file

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
  
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  redis: 
    image: redis
    

  app:
    container_name: password-manager-docker
    restart: always
    build: .
    
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
    links: 
      - mongo
      - redis
    environment: 
      MONGODB_URI: ${MONGODB_URI}
      clientID: ${clientID}
      clientSecret : ${clientSecret}
      PORT: ${PORT}
      NODE_ENV : ${NODE_ENV}
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      JWT_EXPIRE: ${JWT_EXPIRE}
      REFRESH_TOKEN: ${REFRESH_TOKEN}
      JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY}
      JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE: ${JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE}
      JWT_COOKIE: ${JWT_COOKIE}
```

Any suggestion will help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you deploy the app and database separately. I might be wrong, but as I understand you can not use docker-compose with Heroku, so you might want to first get the app at least running.

For building and pushing the app check this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime.
You will need to pass an environment variable to start the app on the right port, so in you Dockerfile use

> EXPOSE $PORT

> CMD npm start -p $PORT

This way you will run the server on the port made available by Heroku.

For redis, you can use an Heroku add-on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis

You will be able to specify add-ons by adding a heroku.yml at the root of your app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setup-defining-your-app-s-environment.

I hope this can help to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How can I handle the environment variables in docker-compoase.yml.I mean do I have to add them manually to heroku ?

Comment: To deploy a dockerized app in Heroku you do not need the docker-compose file, you have to use only the Dockerfile. Heroku passes the $PORT variable automatically, you do not need to set it. In fact you don't even need to expose it, since Heroku will go for the one specified in $PORT automatically. If you want to pass the port as env variable in docker-compose (for local usage), check here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/